# How to use the same script of ReactJS on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't seem to find an answer to this question.

Just to be clear here is my ReactJS main code :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import Page from "../components/MainPage";
import LoginPage from "../components/LoginPage";

ReactDom.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('MainPageTopBar'));
ReactDom.render(<LoginPage />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is my index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Placeholder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style/entry/main.css">
</head>
<body class="body">
<div id="MainPageTopBar">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Placeholder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style/entry/main.css">
</head>
<body class="body">
<div id="app">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is for the first ReactDOM.render to render the index, which it does. I also want the second one to render its own page, login page to be more precise. No error from webpack seems to appear but I get this error : "Target container is not a DOM element" on my browser's console. I use Chrome though I don't think that is the problem.
Here is the LoginPage file :

```
import React from "react";

class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                doesn t matter
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default LoginPage;
```

I figure the problem is in the main.js. Could somebody please tell me what is wrong with the code I have and provide me with the solution?

Comment: depending which html page you are on, one of those document.getElementById will be undefined since on either page only one of those elements exists, May be worth looking into react router, otherwise you would need to consolidate everything into one <App /> component or a different js file controlling each page.

Comment: I will look into react router. You said something about a different js controlling each page. Can you tell me how to do that please?

Comment: You'd have a main.js and you'd have something like a login.js. you'd have to configure webpack or whatever you are using to have an entry for each one and an output. Then you would just replace `<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/main.js"></script>` with login.js.

Comment: I do use webpack and here is my current config: var config = {
    entry: {
        main: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'entry' , 'main.js'),
    }, What do I have to do here to add the login.js as an entry point?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I have added a secondary entry point to the webpack.config.js. I ran webpack --watch again and now I have two different output files for both scripts. Thank you for your time finalfreq :)